# Save FileField file uploads someplace other than MEDIA_ROOT?

Tags: django

Can I use FileField to handle a file, but store it someplace *not* under `MEDIA_ROOT/MEDIA_URL` but somewhere else entirely.

Seeking is to ensure it is not downloadable; although denying read permissions would do the trick here's hoping for something better... like a different directory altogether.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.

First, you can take a look at [handling uploaded files](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files) from the Django docs. If you read it over, basically you can handle the upload of the file within your view in the same part where you are processing your form.

Another option, and one which I think would be better is to use a [custom file storage system](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/#file-storage). You could do this very simply using the existing one as a base but simply change the location, then use it as an argument in your FileField. For example:

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

my_store = FileSystemStorage(location='/some/other/dir')

class SomeModel(models.Model):
      file = models.FileField(storage=my_store)
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Considering that the only actual use of MEDIA_ROOT in all of Django is to determine where uploaded files are stored, seems like it would make more sense to just point MEDIA_ROOT where you want your uploaded files, and then use a different setting for the path to your static assets. This is the approach taken by [Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/) and [django-staticfiles](http://bitbucket.org/jezdez/django-staticfiles/src/), which use STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT settings.

Note that even [the documentation page on serving static assets in development](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) no longer recommends using MEDIA_ROOT for that purpose, it demonstrates using your own STATIC_DOC_ROOT setting.